# jQuery capslock key *held down*

Tags: jquery, keydown, keyup

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    $("#snippet-test").text('keyDown = ' + key); 
});

$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    $("#snippet-test").text('keyUp = ' + key);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="snippet-test">output</div>
```

Hello I am having a bit of trouble with caps lock.

When pressing caps lock, the keydown fires and the console log is fired.  However, when releasing capslock nothing happens...when pressing caps lock again (turning the caps lock state off) the keyup event fires.  Is there anyway around this behavior? I need to be able to detect when caps lock is released.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT I have inserted a snippet** 
-Pressing and releasing any letter shows a keydown then keyup on release. The capslock button behaves differently and shows keydown for one press (nothing for release) then for the second press fires the keyup (when capslock is disabled). I am hoping there is a way around that.

Comment: I don't get the behavior you describe (pressing and release CAPS LOCK triggers a keydown, then a keyup, just like other keys). (I'm testing in Chrome.) But note in your code that you never set `cLock` to anything other than `false`. Please Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: when I press and hold capslock it fires off the console.log('keypress 20'). When releasing capslock it doesn't fire the console.log('keyUp 20') untill I press / release for a second time.  Is that not happening for anyone else?  BTW I apologize for my mistakes when posting.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware of the Stack Snippets, very cool. I have set one up and the example is working and showing the issue.  Pressing and releasing any letter shows a keydown then keyup on release.  The capslock button behaves differently and shows keydown for one press (nothing for release) then for the second press fires the keyup (when capslock is disabled).  I am hoping there is a way around that.

Comment: I don't get the behavior you describe. I tried Chrome and Firefox on Linux, and Chrome, Firefox, and IE11 on Windows. I always get `keydown` when pressing the CAPS LOCK key and `keyup` when releasing it. (Naturally, pressing and releases it toggles the caps lock, I have to press and release again to untoggle it.)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, last night I had the chance to try this out on a windows computer and on windows it behaves like I would like. I get a keydown when pressing and a keyup when releasing.  Right now I am on a Mac, the capslock key has a light on it and it toggles on and off.  The first logs a Keydown and the light goes on, then if you press it again it registers as a Keyup and the light goes off.  I found another post which shows how you can get the state of the key like this: "e.originalEvent.getModifierState("CapsLock")" but that doesn't really help in my case.

Comment: I guess there is no way to tell if the capslock button is being held down on Mac unfortunately..:(  BTW the reason is because the built in Mac Screen reader program uses capslock as their special key which is causing me some issues not being able to detect when it is held

Comment: A friend with a Mac and I were playing around with it, and it definitely looks awkward to get the current state of the capslock from an event related to the capslock key itself. But `e.originalEvent.getModifierState("CapsLock")` works fine when you are processing a keydown or keyup for *other* keys. What is your actual end goal?

Comment: getModifierState works as far as telling me if capslock is on or off but my end goal is being able to determine if capslock is *currently* being held down so that I can fix an issue with my keyboard accessibility that happens with Macs screen reader within my menus.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry not to have any better ideas for you. Good luck!!

Comment: no worries, thank you for the time you spent on this.